# Switch between different tabs using capybara or selenium

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I wish to switch between browser tabs for a feature I am testing. However I have not been able to do this. Have tried using the following:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.first)
```

The idea been that when I am on the second tab the above code should bring it back to the first tab. However this is not working.

I also just tried to close the second tab using this:

```
page.execute_script "window.close();"
```

but this does do anything, the tab is not closed nor is the overall browser window so appears that it is not doing anything.

Had anybody else had problems like this and how did you figure out a solution? I am using FireFox.

Comment: Your approach/code is generally correct (at least it works for me locally). There are two things that might be causing you issues: (1) when a new tab is opened Selenium-Webdriver does not automatically switch to it - ie I am guessing your code is switching from the original tab to the same original tab and (2) it does not look like you can `window.close();` the original tab - ie it will only do something if you have switched to the second tab.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my method for closing new tabs.

```
def close_new_tabs
  window = page.driver.browser.window_handles
    
  if window.size > 1 
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(window.last)
    page.driver.browser.close
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(window.first)
  end
end
```

I call this method anytime a new tab may need to be closed.

Comment: On the topic of tabs how do you create a new tab?

Comment: @Richlewis clicking link with target="blank".

Answer (score 5):

I was able to switch between tabs using the following

```
browser.switch_to.window browser.window_handles.last
```

Answer (score 0):

##### To open a new window from current window:

```
within_window open_new_window do
    # Write your code to handle in new tab
end
```